# Get context size dynamically in flutter

Tags: flutter

In my page I have one `TextField` and when keyboard opening I want get context size. How can I get screen context size when keyboard animating. Can I add listener to context insets?

Comment: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom;   this will give you the padding which is ocupied by system ui (bottom one ).

Comment: this solution I know, but this value not update every time when keyboard animating

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice package about it. By adding this package to your application, you can listen to keyboard movements.
You can make changes on the event you want in onchanged.

install the [keyboard_visibility package:](https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_visibility)

```
import 'package:keyboard_visibility/keyboard_visibility.dart';
    @protected
void initState() {
  super.initState();`

  KeyboardVisibilityNotification().addNewListener(
    onChange: (bool visible) {
      print(visible);

    },
  );
}
```

edit:

keyboard and screen height different. please run code:

```
       @override
       Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       double keyboardHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom;
       double screenAndKeyboardDifferent =                                       
       MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
       MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom;

   return Scaffold(

       body: Container(
       padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
       child: Column(
       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
       children: [
        TextFormField(),
         Text("keyboard height:" + keyboardHeight.toString()),
         Text("screen and keyboard different: " +
          screenAndKeyboardDifferent.toString())
      ],
     ),
   ));
  }
```

Comment: but I don't want listen ``onchange`` notification. I want get context size of screen,